# How to copy data from SQL table to create sub folders for each table data using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Lets say I have 3 tables Table1,Table2,Table3. I want these to be in CSV files in the azure data lake storage. This I have already completed but they are together in a folder. How to copy them in 3 different folders like Table1,Table2,Table3

Comment: can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I have copied these 3 table data as csv into the azure storage account. But they are copied in the same location

Answer (score 1):

> How to copy them in 3 different folders like Table1,Table2,Table3

Use the below approach to achieve your requirement.

Create the datasets of SQL database and ADLS like below.

**SQL database dataset:**

```
{
    "name": "AzureSqlTable1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "table_name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "schema": [],
        "typeProperties": {
            "schema": "dbo",
            "table": {
                "value": "@dataset().table_name",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ADLS dataset with parameter:**

```
{
"name": "target_csv_files",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "folder_name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "table_name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "DelimitedText",
    "typeProperties": {
        "location": {
            "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
            "fileName": {
                "value": "@dataset().table_name",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "folderPath": {
                "value": "@dataset().folder_name",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "fileSystem": "data"
        },
        "columnDelimiter": ",",
        "escapeChar": "\\",
        "firstRowAsHeader": true,
        "quoteChar": "\""
    },
    "schema": []
}
}
```

Then create a lookup activity with `SELECT name FROM sys.Tables;` script to take list of tables.

[image]

Lookup will give output like below:

[image]

Give this array to a ForEach and inside ForEach use the copy activity. Give the source and sink of the copy activities like below with dynamic contents  `@item().name` and `@concat(item().name,'.csv')`.

**Source:**

[image]

**Sink:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]